# What is the technique called when series of events in a film are played in reverse order?

Tags: terminology

For example, [Memento (2000)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0209144/) is presented as two different sequences of scenes: a series in black-and-white that are shown chronologically, and **a series of color sequences shown in reverse order**.

Another example I can remember is Seinfeld's 9th season episode "The Betrayal".

Does this style have a name in movie jargon?

Comment: Non linear style of making?

Comment: [Nonlinear Storyline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_narrative) is a technique where events are portrayed out of chronological order, but not necessarily with reverse chronology. So yes, your hunch was correct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, I've found out that term is [Reverse Chronology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_chronology). Wikipedia gives some nice details together with the [examples of use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_chronology#Examples_of_use) in [movies & TV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_chronology#Film).

> *Reverse chronology* is a method of story-telling whereby the plot is
>   revealed in reverse order.
>
> In a story employing this technique, the first scene shown is actually
>   the conclusion to the plot. Once that scene ends, the penultimate
>   scene is shown, and so on, so that the final scene the viewer sees is
>   the first chronologically.
>
> Many stories employ flashback, showing prior events, but whereas the
>   scene order of most conventional films is A-B-C-etc, a film in reverse
>   chronology goes Z-Y-X-etc.

Comment: My hunch was correct after all.

Comment: I was reading about The Betrayal and it leaded me to the Wikipedia link.

Comment: So would Pulp Fiction be "blender chronology"?

Comment: The correct term for Pulp Fiction is [Nonlinear Storyline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_narrative).

Comment: "See also
    Reverse chronology"
It's on the Wikipedia page of Memento...

Answer (score 6):

Well, "Reverse Chronology" sounds like a fitting term.